# How to run MVC 4 of VS 2012 on web server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC 4 application and runs well on my local machine.
What do I have to do further in Visual Studio 2012 to run my website in web server?
Do I have to make some files by VS 2012 to deploy a website in web server?

Comment: what do you mean by 'web server'.  Are you asking how to run the website in IIS on your local dev machine?  Or, are you asking what prerequisites are required to run MVC 4 on a new Windows server?

Comment: What is your server configuration? (OS, IIS, etc)

Comment: I would like to run website on new Windows server - Apache. How to compile my project in VS 2012 to run my web site?

Comment: I have two servers. IIS and Apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything specific in Visual Studio.

- Make sure you have .net 4.0 and MVC installed on your server.
- Configure your app pool to be the same architecture as your Webapp(x86, x64).
- Change your web.config
- Create a virtual directory/application on your ISS.
- Configure authentication options of your app(probably you will need anonymous and forms)

When you publish/build your website you can just copy the entire content to your IIS directory and it should work.

Comment: 1.Is it necessary condition to have MVC on server?

Comment: 2. What files do I need to copy on server?

Comment: 3. What do I have to change in web config? Is some instruction there to deploy website on web server?

Comment: 1)Maybe it's worth a try not installing MVC, i just do that :p
2)When you select your mvc project, do a publish to your local drive, just copy that folder.
3)Web config needs to contain the correct connectionstring for your database and maybe some logging files needs to be adjusted.

Comment: 2. Should I copy three folders created by VS 2012 and file of Microsoft Visual Studio Solution? 3. Do you have an instance of connection string?:) show me please

Comment: <add name="NameOfTheConnString" connectionString="Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword"/>
And you need to copy all the folders